# How to ignore a folder in lint-staged?

Tags: eslint, lint-staged

I have this configuration file for [lint-staged](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lint-staged):

```
{
  "*.{ts,tsx}": ["eslint --fix"],
  "*.css": "stylelint --fix"
}
```

However, I want to skip/ignore the `coverage` folder.

I tried:

```
{
  "*.{ts,tsx}": ["eslint --fix"],
  "*.css": "stylelint --fix",
  "ignore":["coverage"]
}
```

But it did not work.